# Styling Polymer Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I am trying to make an paper-card element change colors based on the status of the customers data on Fire base, but for some reason the color only updates on the second click of the customer. Right now I have the paper cards ID set to the firebase data in order to make it change colors. Here's my elements style code:

```
<style is="custom-style">
:host {
  display: block;
}
#cards {
  @apply(--layout-vertical);
  @apply(--center-justified);
}
.row {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
paper-card {
  padding: 20px;
}
#check {
  float: right;
  bottom: 15px;
  --paper-card
}
#Done {
  --paper-card-header: {
    background: var(--paper-green-500);
  };

  --paper-card-content: {
    background: var(--paper-green-300);
  };
}
#Default {
  /*Apply Default Style*/
  /*--paper-card-content: {*/
  /*  background: var(--paper-red-500);*/
  /*};*/
}
paper-icon-button.check{
  color: var(--paper-green-500);
}
paper-icon-button.check:hover{
  background: var(--paper-green-50);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#check::shadow #ripple {
  color: green;
  opacity: 100%;
}
.iron-selected{
  color: green;
}
```

And here is the template:

```
  <template>

<firebase-collection
  location="https://calllistmanager.firebaseio.com/Wilson"
  data="{{wilsonData}}"></firebase-collection>

  <div id="cards">
    <template id="cards" is="dom-repeat" items="{{wilsonData}}" as="customer">
      <paper-card id="{{customer.status}}" class="{{customer.status}}" heading="[[customer.__firebaseKey__]]">
        <div class="card-content">
            <span>Phone: </span><span>[[customer.number]]</span>
            <span>Status: </span><span>[[customer.status]]</span>
            <paper-icon-button style="color: green" id="check" on-tap="checktap" icon="check">
            </paper-icon-button>
          </div>
      </paper-card>
  </template>
  </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
```

(function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'list-display',

```
  properties: {
    wilsonData: {
      type: Object,
      observer: '_dataObserver'
    }
  },

  ready: function() {
      var listRef = new Firebase("https://calllistmanager.firebaseio.com/Wilson");
    },

  checktap: function(e){
    // e.model.customer.status = "Done";
    console.log("Starting Status: " + e.model.customer.status);
    ref = new Firebase("https://calllistmanager.firebaseio.com/Wilson")
    var stat;
    var store = ref.child(e.model.customer.__firebaseKey__);
    store.on("value", function(snapshot){
      stat = snapshot.child("status").val();
    });
    if(stat == "Done"){
      store.update({
        "status": "Default"
      });
      e.model.customer.status = "Default";
    }
    else {
        store.update({
        "status": "Done"
      });
      e.model.customer.status = "Done";
    }
    console.log("Ending Status: " + e.model.customer.status);
    this.updateStyles()
  }
});
```

})();

at first I thought the problem may be that the function runs updateStyles(); faster than firebase can update but it always works fine on the second click...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be caused by the call to firebase. `store.on("value",` is not a synchronous function. However, later in your code you assume that you already have a value, that will be set later on whenever the value event fires. You could try adding the rest of your code in the event handler. Like this:

```
checktap: function(e){
    // e.model.customer.status = "Done";
    console.log("Starting Status: " + e.model.customer.status);
    ref = new Firebase("https://calllistmanager.firebaseio.com/Wilson")
    var store = ref.child(e.model.customer.__firebaseKey__);
    store.once("value", function(snapshot){
        var stat = snapshot.child("status").val();
        if(stat == "Done"){
          store.update({
            "status": "Default"
          });
          e.model.set("customer.status", "Default");
        }
        else {
            store.update({
            "status": "Done"
          });
          e.model.set("customer.status", "Done");
        }
        console.log("Ending Status: " + e.model.customer.status);
        this.updateStyles();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Essentially, you wait until the `stat` variable has been set to do the rest of your tasks. Also note, the `bind(this)` at the end, which will allow you to update the the styles from the event handler.

**Update**

There are a couple of more issues. First it's better to uses classes for changing the styles and not IDs. IDs should not change. Then, to bind to the class attribute, use the `$` sign. When you update the model, you should use the `set` API.
Have a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s7w9FeqWAkMZNFvrWKdW). It is a small working example (only works in Chrome) that changes styles when you click the checkmark. It does not use Firebase, however.

Here's how you could to the style with classes.

```
.Done {
  --paper-card-header: {
    background: var(--paper-green-500);
  };

  --paper-card-content: {
    background: var(--paper-green-300);
  };
}
```

And in your template:

```
<paper-card class$="{{customer.status}}" heading="[[customer.__firebaseKey__]]">
```

Comment: I added .bind(this) to the end of my function and then i got an error for updatestyles. Seems to be calling the function without the capital S now...strange

Comment: Did you also move the rest of the code into the event handler?

Comment: Also, I just noticed I had a typo in the code, which I have just corrected.

Comment: What do you mean by the other code? It's all in the event hander function already

Comment: I'm referring to the on-value event handler of Firebase. Essentially, I'm just asking if you have tried copy pasting the whole solution above or just appended the `bind`. Since I can't run your code, I can't verify that it really works.

Comment: All I did was append the .bind

Comment: And I understand what you mean now, and I will try this tomorrow after work and repot back. It's 3:00am now, I'm off to bed for today

Comment: okay I added all of the code to the ."on("value", " like above,and now the styles won't change at all. The console just shows the value switching from done to default rapidly.

Comment: The on-value handler will trigger whenever the value of the customer changes. As you toggle the value of the status inside the on-value handler, this will result in an endless loop of changes.

Comment: So maybe if move the on-value function inside my if else statent

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in checktap? Read the status from Firebase? Update the status based on some criterion?

Comment: I want to check the status of the status var and then adjust it to a new var depending on this result, and then change the class that is binded to this value, then update my styles to make the change appear

Comment: You could try using `store.once(..` instead of `store.on(...`

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit, with some bits and pieces here and there. Maybe you can have another look and try the code snipptes again. They have changed.

Comment: I'm about to get off work in a few minutes and try the new solution, and will report back. Thanks for all your help BTW

Comment: I tried the new solution, but am still seeing the same results. The style will only change after the second click of the button

Comment: Actually, this worked! I had forgot to add the e.model.customer.status.set() to the if statement. My question now is, if we are writing to the database using the .set() command, can't we just loose the update() functions in the if statement?

Comment: I don't know too much about Firebase. You could just try and see if that works. Otherwise you could ask a new question to get an answer from someone with more Firebase expertise.

Comment: I removed them, and now it works flawlessly. Thanks for your help!